# Prefect caching through a file target

Tags: python, prefect

After reading the documentation on [Output Caching based on a file target](https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/persistence.html#output-caching-based-on-a-file-target)
, I figured this workflow should be an example of output caching:

```py
from time import sleep
from prefect import Flow, task
from prefect.engine.results import LocalResult


@task(target="func_task_target.txt", checkpoint=True, 
      result=LocalResult(dir="~/.prefect"))
def func_task():
    sleep(5)
    return 99

with Flow("Test-cache") as flow:
    func_task()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flow.run()
```

I would expect `func_task` to run one time, get cached, and then use the cached value next time I run the flow. However, it seems that `func_task` runs each time.

Where am I going wrong? Or have I misunderstood the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting environment variable `PREFECT__FLOWS__CHECKPOINTING` to `True`

```
import os
os.environ["PREFECT__FLOWS__CHECKPOINTING"] = "true"
```

you can also change the results dir

```
os.environ["PREFECT__HOME_DIR"] = "path to dir"
```

Comment: This indeed works, **as long as I set the variable before I import prefect**. Thank you.

Comment: true instead of True

Comment: How did you find this? It works for me but it's not in their docs on "Output Caching Based on a File Target." https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/persistence.html#output-caching-based-on-a-file-target

Comment: have a look at this link https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/results.html#pipeline-persisted-result-objects