# Prefect still treats files as cached after I've deleted them

Tags: python, prefect

The rest of my team uses Prefect for "pipelining stuff", so I'm trying to do a thing in Prefect, but for this thing, I need behavior sort of like GNU `make`. Specifically, I want to specify a filename at runtime, and

1. If the file doesn't exist, I want Prefect to run a specific task.
2. If the file exists, I want Prefect to skip that task.

I read through
[Prefect caching through a file target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67905178/prefect-caching-through-a-file-target/67905833#comment129051302_67905833)
and got that system mostly working: behavior 2 works, and if I run it twice, then the second time is faster because the task is skipped. But behavior 1 doesn't work. If I run the flow, delete the file, and run the flow again, I want it to run the task, but it doesn't, and I still don't have my file at the end. How do I get it to run the task in this situation? Here's a little example.

```
import os 
os.environ["PREFECT__FLOWS__CHECKPOINTING"] = "true" 
from prefect.engine.results import LocalResult 
from prefect import task, Flow, Parameter 
import subprocess 

@task(result=LocalResult(), target="{myfilename}") 
def make_my_file(myfilename):
    subprocess.call(["touch", myfilename])
    subprocess.call(["sleep", "1"])
    return True

with Flow("makemyfile") as flow:
    myfilename       = Parameter("myfilename",    default="foo.txt")
    is_my_file_done  = make_my_file(myfilename)
    flow.run(myfilename = "bar.txt")
```

To see the behavior:

```
python demo_flow.py # makes bar.txt
python demo_flow.py # skips the task
rm bar.txt
python demo_flow.py # still skips the task! Rawr!
```

Answer (score 0):

For `prefect2` I guess that the answer should have been:
https://docs.prefect.io/concepts/tasks/#refreshing-the-cache

But somehow in current version (2.7.9) there is no `refresh_cache` on the task.

The only way I found to selectively delete the cache from a given flow is to:

- in the table `task_run_state` update `data` from all `task_runs` from given flow_run to null
- in the table `task_run_state_cache` delete all the updated `task_run_state`.

I have also found somewhere on the internet that some people update / create own the `cache_key_fn`. Unfortunately I can't find where.

I have found that it should be easier to manage after following fix is implemented:
https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/8239